# Responsive table in DataTable

Tags: php, css, laravel, datatables

My page looks like this:
[image: photo]

I want to add scrollX when page is too small so I must add line
`scrollX: true`

When I add page looks like this:
[image: photo]

DataPicker is behind rows and line of column is not in this same line but scrollX work(look picture). When I write in input and ajax load data that line of column works fine but datapicker still not work. How can I repair this?

Code _table.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="policies-table" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Numer polisy</th>
            <th>Produkt</th>
            <th>Data wystawienia</th>
            <th>Wartość</th>
            <th>Składka</th>
            <th>Wystawiający</th>
            <th>Akcje</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Ajax load:

```
$('#policies-table').DataTable({
    ajax: {url:"url",
    type: "POST",
    'headers': {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}},
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    jQueryUI: true,
    order: [[ 2, "desc" ]],
    ........
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate the z-index of the datapicker? Tip: You will get much more, and better, responses if you show a code example of your problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Yes.
`.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$('#policies-table').DataTable({responsive: true} );`

Or If you are using bootstrap, you cant try this

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='your classes'>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what OP asked.

Comment: Yeap. I'm using bootstrap. I have this code but still not work. I'm thinking that the problem is releated to CSS.

Comment: remove `<div class='table-responsive'>` and try `"scrollX": true`